# MySQL update with a subquery

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to update a specific row in a table based on another value in that table, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it:

```
UPDATE users AS a SET a.val = (SELECT value FROM users WHERE userid = 4) WHERE a.userID = 1
```

but I am getting the error

```
Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` syntax and a non-equi join

```
UPDATE users a JOIN users b
    ON a.userID = 1
   AND b.userid = 4
   SET a.value = b.value
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271979/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you! Slightly different from SQL server, which is what I'm used to.

Answer (score 0):

use join and subquery,

```
update users as a
join (select value  
      from users 
      where userid=4) as sub
set a.val=sub.val
where a.userID=1;
```

The subquery will retrieve the value from the users table where userid=4 and then joins this subquery with the users table where userID=1 and updates the val column.